# Magento 2: Reference one Store to multiple Websites

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I'm going to build a Magento 2 webshop. I would like to have multiple websites (one for each country we're shipping to). Each website should contain a single store and multiple store views with all provided languages.

Is it possible to create the store and the store views just once and reference in different Websites to them? As far as I could find out Magento is only allowing that one store belongs to one Website.

Is there some kind of workaround to be able to reference a store to many websites?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way to do it.

1. You must create different store for every website
2. However you  can use same root category for every store if that helps you somehow.